# How to unmark selection in elisp?

Tags: region, mark

I wish to remove selection programatically, what is the proper way of doing this? Specifically I wish to write a function to make swiper search in buffer with selected text, but it needs to remove selection before open swiper window. Here's the function

```
(defun sandric/swiper-or-region (beg end)
  "Swiper region or 'empty string' if none highlighted."
  (interactive (if (use-region-p)
                   (list (region-beginning) (region-end))
                 (list nil nil)))
  (if (and beg end)
      (progn
        (keyboard-quit)
        (swiper (buffer-substring-no-properties beg end)))
    (swiper)))
```

As you can see there's a `(keyboard-quit)` call before swiper command to open swiper buffer, but with that it simply discards swiper buffer as if ESC was called already after swiper buffer appeared. So I need to find a better way.

Answer (score 15):

Ok, I found the answer almost immediately after posting question. The function name is `deactivate-mark` if anyone has the same question. Its described [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/The-Mark.html). Updated code:

```
(defun sandric/swiper-or-region (beg end)
  "Swiper region or 'empty string' if none highlighted."
  (interactive (if (use-region-p)
                   (list (region-beginning) (region-end))
                 (list nil nil)))
  (if (and beg end)
      (progn
        (deactivate-mark)
        (swiper (buffer-substring-no-properties beg end)))
    (swiper)))
```

Comment: @Jules I can mark my own answer as accepted only in 2 days unfortunately.

Comment: Oh well the more you know!

Comment: Please consider providing the updated code, and linking to the Elisp manual, node [The Mark](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/The-Mark.html).